# C++ compilation in linux for newbie

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

Suppose my project directory has 2 sub-directories A and B, A directory contains: `A.h` and `A.cpp`, B directory contains: `B.h` and `B.cpp` and my root directory contains `main.cpp`

Now the contents:

A.h:

```
#include"../B/B.h"
a();
```

A.cpp:

```
#include"A.h"
a() 
{   
 b();
 }
```

B.h:

> b();

B.cpp:

```
b()
{
 cout<<"Blah Blah Blah";
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include"A/A.h"
main()
{
  a();
}
```

and compile the code using:

> c++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp

Question is simple: In the first file (`A.h`), I would not like to write the first line as
`#include"../B/B.h"`
How may I change it to `#include"B/B.h"` or `#include"B.h"`?

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? I'd assume G++ ... but one never knows.

Comment: Why do you need to include B.h in A.h? I don't see any dependency there.

Comment: @@J.N:I am using ubuntu, so i assume gcc. I just typed "c++ main.cpp A.cpp B.cpp" in the command line I am not very familiar with their difference. if there is a place or command I can check, please let me know ...to let you know the result :)

Comment: @@akhisp: I am calling b() which is defined in B.h. I guess it is called a dependency and needs an inclusion. isn't it?

Comment: Side Note: Your headers are missing [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Comment: @rahman: The fact that a() calls b() should ideally be hidden and not exposed in the header file, it should only be included in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this layout, with `A` containing `A.h` and `A.cpp`, `B` containing `B.h` and `B.cpp`, and `main.cpp` in the root directory:

```
$ ls *.cpp A B
main.cpp

A:
A.cpp  A.h

B:
B.cpp  B.h
```

You can use `#include "B/B.h" and compile your program with

```
c++ -I. main.cpp A/A.cpp B/B.cpp
```

The `-I` flag tells the compiler where to look for include files. If you are using GCC, see [the GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

**Source file contents**

I edited your example to make it compile and run:

*A/A.h:*

```
#include "B/B.h"

void a();
```

*A/A.cpp:*

```
#include "A.h"

void a() 
{
    b();
}
```

*B/B.h:*

```
void b();
```

*B/B.cpp:*

```
#include <iostream>

void b()
{
    std::cout<<"Blah Blah Blah";
}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "A/A.h"

int main()
{
    a();
}
```

Comment: And if I want to use  only  `#include "B.h" instead of `#include "B/B.h", i should give -I./B  instead of -I.

Comment: Yes, you can use `-I./B`. You can search for include files in both directories with: `-I. -I./B`

Answer (score 1):

you can tell the compiler, in which directory/ies the header files are. For gcc/g++ this is the **-I path** option. **path** can be absolut (e.g. `/home/me/src/projectx/`) or relative (e.g.: `..`).

You can set it to the top level directory (the onw, where "B" is in) an the write

```
#include <B/B.h>
```

and compile it with the **-I option** ponting to your top level directory.

Answer (score 1):

g++ -I[include dir] is exactly for this purpose.